# How to cast an Iterator of a class to an Iterator of a subclass thereof?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I tried to cast an Iterator of a class to an iterator of a subclass of said class. This gave me an "inconvertible types" error. Why is this not possible and what is the most elegant way to work around it? (Or alternatively, why is it a bad idea if it is?)

Using a for-each loop is not a solution in this case: I'm trying to implement `iterator()` and the easiest way to do this would be to return the `iterator()` of one of my class' fields, but that one doesn't have the exact required type. I can't change the signature of my `iterator()`either.

```
public interface SomeoneElsesInterface {
    public Iterator<SomeoneElsesInterface> iterator();
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass implements SomeoneElsesInterface {
    final MyAbstractClass[] things;
    public MyAbstractClass(SomeoneElsesInterface... things) {
         this.things = (MyAbstractClass[]) things;
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    public MyClass(MyAbstractClass thing1, MyAbstractClass thing2) {
        super(thing1, thing2);
    }

    public Iterator<SomeoneElsesInterface>() {
        return (Iterator<SomeoneElsesInterface>) Arrays.asList(things).iterator();
    }
}
```

I could, of course, just change the type of `things`. However, I would need a lot of casts in other places in that case. I do know that my constructor won't be called with objects that are not `MyAbstractClass`s but I cannot change the interface anyway.

Comment: What (if anything) is the relationship between the type of the class and the type of the contained field? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks to be as simple as using [*explicit type argument specification*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20explicit%20type%20argument%20specification?):

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    // ...

    public Iterator<SomeoneElsesInterface> iterator() {
      return Arrays.<SomeoneElsesInterface>asList(things).iterator();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Arrays#asList()` is inferring that you want a list of type `List<MyAbstractClass>`, which will yield an iterator of type `Iterator<MyAbstractClass>`. Since `Iterator`'s type parameter is not *covariant*, you cannot supply an `Iterator<MyAbstractClass>` where an `Iterator<SomeoneElsesInterface>` is required. By forcing `Arrays#asList()` to create a list of type `List<SomeoneElsesInterface>`, as shown above, you also wind up with the intended iterator type coming back from your call to `Iterable#iterator()`.

The author of `SomeoneElsesInterface` would have been kinder to specify the return type of its `iterator()` method as `Iterator<? extends SomeoneElsesInterface>`.

Answer (score 5):

I think from your question you're trying to do something like this:

```
Iterator<Object> original = ...
Iterator<String> converted = (Iterator<String>)original;
```

Is that correct?

If so, that is, unfortunately, impossible. The problem is that `original` can contain objects that are not `String`s, so allowing that cast would break the generics contract, i.e. `converted` could contain something that is not a `String`.

I don't think there is an elegant workaround for this.

You say the easiest way to implement `iterator()` is to return an instance field's iterator, so I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
class IterableThing implements Iterable<Foo> {
    private Collection<Bar> someStuff;

    public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
        return (Iterator<Foo>)someStuff.iterator();
    }
}

class Bar {
}
class Foo extends Bar {
}
```

If `someStuff` can be guaranteed to contain only instances of `Foo`, then can you declare `someStuff` to be a `Collection<Foo>` rather than a `Collection<Bar>`? If not, then it doesn't really make sense to just return `someStuff`'s iterator because it might contain something that is not a `Foo`.

I guess you need to think about what guarantees you can actually make. If you can't guarantee that `someStuff` only contains `Foo`s then you will probably have to maintain your own state, or filter the contents of `someStuff` on demand.

EDIT: You've updated your question with code. Awesome.

So it looks like you're actually trying to return an iterator over the superclass of the type. That makes things a lot easier.

In your particular case, you can probably solve it with this:

```
return Arrays.<SomeoneElsesInterface>asList(things).iterator();
```

It'll generate some warnings, but that's OK because you know that you've guaranteed type safety.

Comment: Essentially, yes. However in my case `original` is actually an `Iterator` of `Subclass`, and I want `converted` to be an `Iterator` of a superclass of `Subclass`. Thus, I can guarantee that original only contains elements that are (transitively) instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `for-each` loop instead of `Iterator`.

`for-each` was introduced from **Java 1.5**

See this link for further details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

What if you change `Arrays.asList(things)` to `Arrays.asList((SomeoneElsesInterface[]) things)`? Once the array is cast to the right type the List and Iterator should follow.

Answer (score -1):

Example of Java for-each (complementing Kumar answer):

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add( "one" );
strings.add( "two" );
strings.add( "three" );

for ( String item : strings ) {
    System.out.println( item );
}
```